# Multiple table queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

I am having problems with creating a query.

What I am trying to achieve is create a query which conforms to the following criteria

```
   Show all records in table house where 
tbl_house.townId =tbl_town.townId 
and house.type = “3bedrooms”
```

What I have tried so far

```
 var house = 
    From m in db.tbl_house 
    Where m.townId ==  tbl_town.townId && m.Bedrooms == "3bedrooms" 
                   Select m
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated

update

There are three estate agencies one, two and three
There is an account for each estate agency so when the estate agency logs on I want to only show 
Houses for that town with a specified housetype.

All houses have a townID

Example:  house 1 could have a townId of 3 which   = town3  and a housetype = “3bedrooms”

house 2 could have an townId of 3 which   = town3 and a housetype = “2bedrooms”

house 3 could have an townId of 4 which   = town4  and a housetype = “2bedrooms”

So what I am trying to do is select all houses with a townId of 3 and a housetype =”3bedrooms”
And show them for the estate agency which has the townId of 3 associated with it.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense... what value of tbl_house.houseId are you interested in? Do you want customer records for a specific house, customers for all houses, etc? Each of those has a slighlty different solution.

Comment: Problem with LinQ syntax – not worked with LinQ much!

Comment: We can help you with the LINQ syntax but your question doesn't make any more sense now than it did before. what do you mean by "where tbl_house.townId = tbl_town.townId" -- does that mean *any* townId in the entire table? a specific townId? I'll try to answer your question but its likely to be wrong until you can be more clear...

Comment: _Problem with LinQ syntax_. What problem? Please show error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not really clear what your asking, but it seems like you're asking for "all records from table A ('house') that have a matching record in table B ('town')". If that's not true, you need to explain what "tbl_house.townId = tbl_town.townId" means, because it doesn't really make sense otherwise. If that *is* what you want, then you just need to check to see if the foreign key field has a value or not:

```
var house = from m in db.tbl_house
            where m.townId.HasValue() && m.Bedrooms == "3bedrooms"
            select m;
```

The problem with the query you tried is that `tbl_town.townId` doesn't make sense where you put it. `tbl_town` is a set of objects, representing an entire table. In that context, `townId` is a field  *definition*, but you are trying to compare it to an actual field in a singe entity from your `tbl_house` entity set. The two things are not the same, and you can't compare them directly. It would be like saying `where m.Bedrooms = String` -- its just not syntactically correct.

EDIT:

By your updated question it seems like you know the town ID of the town you're looking for; in that's the case, then just filter on that. I'm not sure why you are trying to use "tbl_town.townId" when you know the ID you want, based on the agency.

The syntax here depends entirely on the direction of your relationships; for example, lets say your have an Agency object that has a TownId, you would just need to filter on that:

```
var agency = this.GetTheCurrentAgencySomehow();
var house = from m in db.tbl_house
            where m.townId == agency.townId && m.Bedrooms == "3bedrooms"
            select m;
```

On the other hand, if your Town object has an AgencyId, you would probably use the navigation properties to get from house -> town -> agency:

```
var agency = this.GetTheCurrentAgencySomehow();
var house = from m in db.tbl_house
            where m.town.agencyId == agency.agencyId && m.Bedrooms == "3bedrooms"
            select m;
```

Without knowing more about the actual implementation details of your data model there's no way to really be more specific.

Comment: I think `tbl_town` is a class name _and_ the entity set name. I see it happening all the time, no pluralization: very confusing. In your answer you should probably do `where m.townId == 3`, but then: what's the OP's problem?